# Issue converting docx to pdf using XHTMLImporterImpl

Tags: java, html, pdf, docx4j

Ive updated docx4j from from 8.3.9 to 11.4.11 ow that Im running java 17 and when we try to convert docx to pdf we receive a noSuchMethodError.  On research the RangeFinder Class has changed where the constructor start takes  2 args was removed

```
public RangeFinder(String startElement, String endElement) {
        
        this.startElement = "org.docx4j.wml." + startElement;
        this.endElement   = "org.docx4j.wml." + endElement;
    }
```

only the default constructor is present in the core lib

How to solve this issue?

Tried the older version and different versions of the lib, saw that the class changed 8.3.10, so it appears it has been an issue

checked the docx4j forum and saw no reports

One solution I have is to make the change to the source and recompile the class

Answer (score 0):

Please see just published https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/org.docx4j/docx4j-ImportXHTML-core v11.4.10